# JSON object should appear in div when click on submit

Tags: jquery, html, json, jquery-ui

I am working on wijmo (wijgrid)....I want to display my JSON objects will come inside div when submit ....

I have tried this code but its only working for single input but I want every inputs value of form should appear inside div..

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#addable").submit(function() {
        if(!$("#addable").validate().form()){ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        } else{
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "addUser",
                data : JSON.stringify($('#addable').serializeObject()),
                dataType : "json",
                contentType : "application/json",
            });
        }

        $('#myoutput').append('<div>Number of elements :'+$("#addable").val()+'</div>');
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="myoutput"></div>
```

Please help!! Thanks Tina!!

Comment: I would recommend passing your data as a javascript object and not manually stringifying it when you hand it over to ajax(). Read the jQuery documentation, I'm not completely clear on if that would actually work or not, but I know it works if you don't stringify the object. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a synchronicity problem : when you execute the append, you don't yet have the result of the ajax query. You must define a `success` callback to execute it on success of the ajax call.
2. you're not trying to use the result of your call : you're just adding a div with the number of elements as what is yet in `$("#addable").val()`. It's not clear what you want to achieve.